# Remove first character from a string if it satisfies an if statement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, string, if-statement

I have a bunch of phone numbers and some contain a 1 in front of them e.g. "18885556607" and I would like to simply remove the 1. I can't just remove all first characters because there are numbers like "8665558411"

---

Here is the code I've tried:

```
def splitme(s):
    if (s[:1] == "1"):
        return s[2:]
    else: 
        return(s)
```

expression:

```
splitme( !Phone! )
```

---

The field is a string field, please let me know what I need to change.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: This question is all but pure Python and thus better researched at [So].

Comment: Do you have to be careful with number starting with a "real" valid 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python starts counting at `0`.

Here's what a quick test looks like:

```
>>> x = '18885556607'
>>> y = '8665558411'
>>> x[0]
'1'
>>> x[1:]
'8885556607'
>>>
```

So you can write your code as:

```
def splitme(s):
    if (s[0] == "1"):
        return s[1:]
    else: 
        return(s)
```

Comment: This solution works.

However it seems odd to me that if I want to create a two new fields one for the phone number and one for the extension I need to use extension = !Phone![10:] and phone = !Phone![:10] to get the full number. If it starts counting at 0 should those not need to be changed?

Comment: @user3251415 Sorry I missed your comment here.  In the square brackets, to the right of the colon `[:10]` = display up to (and not including) the character in position 10.  To the left of the colon `[10:]` display from (and including) the character in position 10 (so it uses the first 10 characters - the one at position 10 is the 11th character).